# Importing psycopg 2 on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Every time i run the import command on the jupyter notebook (Python3) i get An error that indicates that there is no module named psycopg 2.

Comment: Try these commands - ```!pip install psycopg2``` or ```pip install -I psycopg2``` these commands have helped me in the past.

Comment: It's properly installed but everytime i try to import them gives me an error.

Comment: Best guess is you have both Python2 and Python3 installed in the system and `pip` is the Python2 version. See if there is a `pip3` and if so use that to `psycopg2` so it shows up in the Python3 site-packages or equivalent.